# ImportError: cannot import name 'VideoCapture'

Tags: python, video-capture

I'm writing a quick Python script that uses VideoCapture.  At the start of the script, I have this:

```
 from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getVids.py", line 4, in <module>
    from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
ImportError: cannot import name 'VideoCapture'
```

When I run:

```
pip3 install skvideo
```

I get:

```
Collecting skvideo
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement skvideo (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for skvideo
```

Any idea how to fix / where to go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: If scikit-video it should be: `pip3 install sk-video`

Answer (score 4):

The pip package providing this python module/package is call `sk-video`.

```
pip3 install sk-video
```

Comment: When I run that, I get: Requirement already satisfied: sk-video in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sk-video)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sk-video)

Comment: Could it be that you have installed the dependency for python 3 but your script is executed using python 2?

Comment: I just tried executing script with python3 and checking my python --version (and it gives back 3.6...) :(

Comment: So if you start `python3` and execute `import skvideo` it fails?

Comment: Strangely, when I start Python (3.6) and import skvideo, it works...Now I'm very confused...

Comment: Probably your script uses another interpreter then. Also, are you using virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
sudo pip install sk-video
```

as suggested in their installation guide. http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/

Answer (score 0):

This smells like an environment variable problem. You shouldn't need `sudo` or administrator privileges to do this.

First, make sure that you run your script inside a virtual environment:

1. Create a Virtualenv: `virtualenv my_env`
2. Activate it: `source my_env/bin/activate`
3. Install your requirements: `pip install sk-video`
4. Run your script: `python getVids.py`